# HTTPException and IOException correct usage

Tags: java

Whats wrong with the following exception handling... I was told this is not correct, Now my exception handling is no the greatest...

```
  try {

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | HttpException e) {

  } catch (IOException e) {

  }
```

Any guidance?

Comment: Do you want us to tell you that it's a bad idea to swallow exceptions or ask why you would handle `HttpException` the same way you handle `UnsupportedEncodingException `?

Comment: Except the fact that `UnsupportedEncodingException` is already an `IOException`, I don't know ...

Comment: Never seen catching multiple exceptions using OR. Use separate catch block for each exception.

Comment: That means: "I want to handle UEE, HE, and IOE. I want to handle UEE, HE in the same way and to handle IOE differently". It is correct or not depends on your application logic. Although I can't think of logic which handles UEE and HE in the same way.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - this is one of the new features with [JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#multiple). It's useful, *provided that it makes sense to handle the exceptions together.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is something bad between the way that you handle `HttpException` and `IOException`.

The most important part of exception handling is to be sure that:

- You can do something with the exception. If you cannot do anything the best strategy is to re-throw the exception (maybe wrapping it with a exception that has more sense for the upper layers of your application).
- You understand the difference between the conditions that can throw each exception.

For example a `UnsupportedEncodingException` means that Java cannot handle the specified  encoding. If you are working with some WS API, it means that the message format is probably incorrect (Java handles most of the standard encodings out there, so there is a good chance that the message is bad). Note that this is a sub-class of `IOException` thrown by Java when you want to create a `Reader` with an unsupported encoding.

`HttpException` means that you have received an HTTP fault response. Is not a `IOException` since the "data transfer" was good. Is an indication of an error from the server, not in the connection.

`IOException` means that something bad happened while processing the stream (maybe the stream ended in a unexpected way).

Based on the causes of each error, the only thing "bad" in the code is mixin `UnsupportedEncodingException` and `HttpException`. It depends on what you do in the exception handler, but both exceptions has different causes.

Answer (score 0):

Always a good practice to handle each exception in a separate catch block so that an action specific to that exception can be taken.

Answer (score 0):

That's acceptable syntax since Java 7, but since that's (relatively) new, the common idiom is to handle one type per catch.  The only time I would be OK with this syntax is if the catch perfroms exactly the same work for all types in the catch and even then...

You also must remain mindful of the hierarchy of exceptions, I think the multiples are evaluated left to right, but you'd want to check on that before depending on it.